# bootstrap scaffolding.less is changing default style.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA4pP.png)

I added a **navbar** called *stretchy-navigation* to the website. It has a lot of css and less files. it introduces miner changes to the body. Removing header fixes things, but i need the header. by the way, i add my header and footer with jQuery with "load" function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9uHJ.png)

this is *stretchy-navigation* file structure.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking, but seems you just need the stretchy CSS file to load before your primary CSS file so it doesn't get overwritten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the code there are a few things you can try.

1. Force your body css instead of bootstraps with !important

   `font-size:1.6rem !important;`
2. Add a class to your `<body>` tag like `<body class='mybody'>` And then have your css selector target `body.mybody{font-size:1.6rem;}`  By making your css rule more specific it may take precedence.
3. The order of your linking css files might matter. Try putting bootstrap first and then your custom css code.